# Confusion about using descriptors to implement type checking

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working through the *O Reilly Python Cookbook* but Im confused about the following code:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, name=None, **opts):
        self.name = name
        self.__dict__.update(opts)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

# Descriptor for enforcing types
class Typed(Descriptor):
    expected_type = type(None)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
        super().__set__(instance, value)

class Integer(Typed):
    expected_type = int
```

i get how the the instance attribute gets set.

Im confused though about the following line:

```
instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

Why do this? As it means the instance attribute can be given a name different to the one originally set when declaring the class.
For ex:

```
class A:
    x = Integer('d')

b=A()

b.x=5
b.x
<__main__.Integer at 0x1188d1390>

b.d
5
```

We have overridden the name x with b. Why allow this?

Also Im confused about the following in the **init** function:

```
self.__dict__.update(opts)
```

Why might we want to populate a type checking descriptor with additional attributes?

What purpose might these added attributes serve?

Comment: "Why might we want to populate a type checking descriptor with additional attributes?" I mean, the class is called Descriptor, so it seems like a template for any generic descriptor (it's a programming *cookbook* after all). There are many reasons why a descriptor might want to hold internal state.

Comment: I think the ability to set the name to an underlying attribute is a side effect of the requirement to set a name. The cookbook was last updated in 2013, three years before the `__set_name__` method was added to the descriptor protocol, allowing you to write `x = Integer()` and have the descriptor be notified that it was assigned to the name `x`, thus letting you set `self.name` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookbook was last updated in 2013, three years before the release of Python 3.6, which added a `__set_name__` method to the descriptor protocol. This method is automatically called when the descriptor is created, so writing

```
x = Integer()
```

would let the descriptor see that it was assigned to a name `x` and set its own name attribute directly.

```
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, **opts):
        self.__dict__.update(opts)

    # I don't *think* we need to know which class
    # the descriptor is being added to for this use case,
    # but I might be overlooking something
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

---

Additional attributes would let you define a "restricted" type. For instance, you could restrict the value to a range between 1 and 10:

```
class RestrictedInteger(Integer):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not (self.low <= value <= self.high):
            raise ValueError(f"{value} not in range {self.low}-{self.high}")
        super().__set__(instance, value)

class A:
    x = RestrictedInteger(low=1, high=10)
```

Then

```
>>> b = A()
>>> b.x = 5
>>> b.x
5
>>> b.x = 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp.py", line 29, in __set__
    raise ValueError(f"{value} not in range {self.low}-{self.high}")
ValueError: 11 not in range 1-10
>>> b.x = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp.py", line 29, in __set__
    raise ValueError(f"{value} not in range {self.low}-{self.high}")
ValueError: 0 not in range 1-10
```